# Fastest way to send message from one EC2 instance to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Another person owns an AWS account, created an EC2 instance on that account, and has given me SSH access to that EC2 instance.

I need to send messages frequently (multiple times a second) from that EC2 instance to an EC2 instance I will launch myself in my own AWS account.

What is the fastest way to do this, and what is the approximate latency of this process? This is for an extremely latency-sensitive application, so speed is of the utmost importance.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Infrastructure**

A [VPC peering connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html) is probably the lowest latency between AWS accounts.

**Application layer**

Your question is quite vague, so I'm not sure if you need this advice. If you need more advice please edit your question to give more detail.

Setting up a secure connection each time will add quite a bit of latency. So either you have a persistent secure connection (ssh / tls / https) or an insecure connection (http / tcp / udp) if you trust AWS's network.

UDP over VPC peering is probably the quickest connection.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into VPC peering. Any idea how much latency would be incurred?

Comment: Low single digit millisecond. Less if it's in the same AZ, more if it's in the same region, and significantly more between regions